expresiones regulares en APPSCRIPT espacios en blanco
Hola estoy intentando obtener por OCR datos en una fila de un PDF pero no me recupera el valor en letras ¿como identifico los espacios? si pueden ayudarme lo agradezco !!!
en el script intento recuperar el valor con esta instrucción
Logger.log(texto.match(/Nombre del incendio:  \w+\s/))

la apariencia de la fila del documento es asi:

necesito  recuperar el texto "las huellas"

Hola la expresión entiendo que podrías ser así:
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("\\w+\\s*");
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(texto);
if(matcher.find())
    Logger.log(matcher.group());
else
    Logger.log("No se ha podido encontrar ninguna palabra.");

Aclaro con código porque en java no me consta que haya literales de expresiones regulares. En javascript sí las hay y se escriben delimitadas por /.
Otra aclaración es que en java se usa doble \ porque se trata de un caracter que dentro de un string debe ser escapado. En otros lenguajes la forma de la expresión sería con simple \, es decir \w+\s*.
Te dejo la documentación de Pattern.
